# To what extent does learning scheme theory help with more classical algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, algebraic-curves, algebraic-groups

This is a question that has come to mind as I have been studying Vakil’s notes on algebraic geometry.

I am studying this in my own time out of interest and afterwards wish to look at other books (specifically Silverman’s GTM book on Elliptic Curves).

One thing I know about Silverman’s book, and many other similar ones, is that they cover AG from a “classical” perspective - no schemes in sight in proving Bezout’s theorem and so forth as far as I know.

To what extent would my knowledge from Vakil’s notes be applicable to this context? Is there any sense in which much of the general theory seen in, e.g. *the arithmetic of elliptic curves* would be subsumed by what I will have learned while studying schemes?

I have found similar questions through searches, asking which elementary problems schemes can solve. This question is not quite that, as rather I am wondering how the theory of schemes helps simplify or illuminate classical geometry that already has classical proofs at the undergraduate level.

I studied “classical” AG books several years ago at university, so while I remember enough to motivate schemes, I can’t remember enough specifics to note specifically how they can be used here.

Comment: What I take away from it is mainly the generality of the concept of a scheme. By fitting existing theories into this more general framework it becomes more clear what type of assumptions are necessary to make the results work and as such, the results aren't coupled as closely with the applications that motivated their discovery, but instead are accompanied by their most natural assumptions in a sense, exposing the result an sich, revealing how the less general results are only shadows of this more pure Form.

Comment: I hope someone with more practice will give you a better answer, but my understanding is that schemes really shine when you either 1) have to study reduction types (what it really means to have good reduction, what a “good model” is, etc) or 2) when you’re trying to do descent, eg when you go from a nice algebraically closed base field to a general base field where rationality becomes a nontrivial question.

Comment: Have you looked at Lorenzini’s [book](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-9/)? It should be more specifically targeted at your goals.

Comment: I have not - but I have been looking for an arithmetic geometry textbook (with exercises) without success for a while, thank you.

Comment: Working with scheme is essential for intersection theory